# Add a column to dataframe summing another dataframe based on substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am trying to append a column to a dataframe which will sum a count from another dataframe based on the contents of a string cell. The dataframes I have look like this:

```
listy = pd.DataFrame(
    ['auto', 'ford', 'chevy', 'auto worker', 'ford motors', 'chevy trucks'])

listy['count'] = np.random.randint(1,500,size=6)
listy
```

|  | 0 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | auto | 24 |
| 1 | ford | 45 |
| 2 | chevy | 384 |
| 3 | auto worker | 81 |
| 4 | ford motors | 156 |
| 5 | chevy trucks | 66 |

and

```
lister = pd.DataFrame(['auto','ford','chevy'])
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | auto |
| 1 | ford |
| 2 | Chevy |

I'm trying to add a column to lister dataframe that sums listy['count'] of any row where ['0'] contains the value of listy[0]

I have gotten the following code to work for individual words

```
listy[listy[0].str.contains("auto")]['count'].sum()
```

Which returns the value I am looking for. My actual data set is thousands of rows so manually collecting totals just won't do.

I have tried the following code:

```
lister['total'] = listy[listy[0].str.contains(lister[0])]
```

and get the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Which I have tried googling but to no avail. Is this even possible?

I have also tried using split on the multi-word column but have still been unable to come up with totals.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.extract`:

```
pat = f"({'|'.join(lister[0])})"
df = listy.groupby(listy[0].str.extract(pat, expand=False))["count"].sum()
print(df.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
       0  count
0   auto    697
1  chevy    806
2   ford    302
```

Answer (score 0):

This would sum the count of `listy` grouping on strings in `lister`:

```
listy.groupby(lister['0']).sum().reset_index()

    0       count
0   Chevy   384
1   auto    24
2   ford    45
```

Assign if required with something like:

```
df_x = listy.groupby(lister['0']).sum().reset_index()
```